# Multipart parser Performance penalty on large multipart POST on Play-2.0 Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I'm currently trying to implement HTML cleaning service which accepts html source data and cleaning params as multipart form. Problem arises with huge html's. In my test case I use 30mb html text, it takes approx. 20 seconds till controller call (for reference same post to nginx takes less then second), actual html processing takes just 1.5sec. I assume that this may be frameworks body parser. Any clue?

Comment: how long does it take for the controller to be called if you use a different body parser, e.g. raw?

Comment: Kim, raw takes approx. 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a performance bug. You should report it and - for now - do the parsing using a different  library such as Apache Commons FileUpload. It can be integrated with non-servlet-based frameworks quite easily. All you have to do is implement the RequestContext interface and call the parseRequest method. See 
http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#parseRequest(org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext)